# Filling Items in scrapy in different functions across the spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

What I'd want to do is filling item fields defined in item.py in different functions within the spider.py file, say in the start_requests function where all the requests are being made, I'd want to fill a Field called 'item_id'.

```
def start_requests(self):
    forms = []
    for item in self.yhd_items:
        self.item["item_id"] = item.ItemCode
        forms.append(FormRequest(self.base_url + item.ItemCode, method='GET',
                                 callback = self.parse_search_result))

    return forms
```

Note that I made an instance of items up in the init function. 
This way just the item_id filed is being filled and passed to the next parser method(parse_search_result).
Other Fields in item.py will be filled in the next function and passed again to another parser method. 
Would it be a legitimate?

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly what is [`meta` argument](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) for, example:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```

Here we define an item instance in `parse_page1`, filling `main_url` field and then passing the item to `parse_page2` in `meta` dictionary. In `parse_page2`, `other_url` field is set and the item is returned.

Hope this is what you were asking about.

Comment: @mehdix_ You should accept the answer, if it answers your question. On a side note, you should be careful when passing objects, as you are making requests more memory consuming and they are already the most memory consuming component of scrapy.

Comment: If I have two pages - page 2 and page 3 - that have parts of the information to be filled as well, how can I call them sequentially in two different scrapy.Requests? I can pass the half-filled item in 'meta' to both, but I want to ensure that the final 'item' has data from page 1 + page 2 + page 3 - all together